# Python fabric is not executng script locally

Tags: python, ubuntu-14.04, fabric

I am trying to execute bash script on my local machine. The location of the script is `/opt/saas/script.sh`. Below is the function to execute script.

```
# Run script on local machine.
def run_local_script(self, path, script):
    print("Path:"+path)
    with cd(path):
        local('.' + script)
```

But every time I run this, I get this.

```
Path is: /opt/saas/
[localhost] local: ./update_services.sh
/bin/sh: 1: ./update_services.sh: not found

Fatal error: local() encountered an error (return code 127) while executing './update_services.sh'

Aborting.
```

Note: I am trying to running script locally with a prior connection established with a remote machine. I hope that should not effect. I also tried to run the script after `disconnect_all()`, but still no success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `lcd` context manager instead (see [Note](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.10/api/core/context_managers.html#fabric.context_managers.cd)).

```
# Run script on local machine.
def run_local_script(self, path, script):
    print("Path:"+path)
    with lcd(path):
        local('.' + script)
```